# C# OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-access, oledb, oledbdatareader

How to change this:

```
public void Charge(string bankaccountnumber, decimal moneyamount)
    {
       foreach (Bankaccount bankaccountInProcess in bankaccount)
        {
            if (bankaccountnumber == bankaccountInProcess.Bankaccountnumber)

                bankaccountInProcess.ChargeFromBankAccount(moneyamount);

        }

        return;
}
```

To use the OleDbDataReader instead of that foreach?

The moneyamount is inputted in console when asked to input the amount of money to be withdrawn from the bank account and then withdrawn from the BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal (and also from WholeAccountBalance). But there is no moneyamount column in the access file, only WholeAccountBalance and BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal currency columns.

Here is an example how I have changed it in different part of my class:

```
public bool IdentifyUser(string bankAccountnumber, int passWord)
    {


        connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\asd.accdb");
            connection.Open();


        OleDbCommand getOne = new OleDbCommand();
        getOne.Connection = connection;
        getOne.CommandText = "SELECT accounNum, pinCode FROM Account WHERE accountNum = '" +
             bankAccountnumber +"'";
        OleDbDataReader readOne = readOne.ExecuteReader();
        if (readOne.Read())
        {
            int GottenPassWord = (int)readOne["pinCode"];
            if (GottenPassWord == passWord)

            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Account was not found");            
        }
        connection.Close();
        return false;

    }
```

Here's what I have come up so far:

```
public void Charge(string bankaccountnumber, decimal moneyamount)
    {

        connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\asd.accdb");
            connection.Open();

        OleDbCommand getOne = new OleDbCommand();
        getOne.Connection = connection;
        getOne.CommandText = "SELECT accounNum, WholeAccountBalance, BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal FROM Account WHERE accounNum = '" +
             bankaccountnumber + "'";
        OleDbDataReader readOne = readOne.ExecuteReader();
        if (readOne.Read())
        {
        // i dont know what to put here to make this do the same thing as the foreach did

        return;

        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Charging did not work");

            return;

        }
}
```

Comment: For me it's unclear what you want to achieve - firstly: because your example is in your mother tongue instead in English, secondly: because you want to replace navigation on some "in memory" collection using `foreach` loop with `OleDbDataReader`, that is used for operation on records in database. If you have data represented by your collection in the database then use proper SELECT query to extract it from db, similar like you did in your second example (just use `while (reader.Read())` loop for continuously reading all records).

Comment: Sorry, now it's in English. The what foreach did before was that it read Account array where I had all the account info, such us bankaccoutnumber, balance etc. but now im trying to replace that with access database. i hope this helps to understand what im asking here.

Comment: private Account[] accounts;
 
        public BankAccountDatabase()
        {

            accounts = new Account[2];
            accounts[0] = new Account("500500-8080", 1111, 1000m, 1000m);
            accounts[1] = new Account("1", 1, 1000m, 2000m);

            
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Access table `Account` has 3 columns: `accounNum`, `WholeAccountBalance` and `BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal`, then you basically should do something like this (I've also corrected and updated it a little). Just check it as I didn't test it.

```
public void Charge(string bankaccountnumber, decimal moneyamount)
{
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\\asd.accdb"))
    {
        connection.Open();

        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
        {
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT accounNum, WholeAccountBalance, BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal FROM Account WHERE accounNum = @accNum";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accNum", bankaccountnumber);

            using (OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())  //assuming accounNum is an unique field (primary key)
                {
                    decimal balanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal = Convert.ToDecimal(reader["BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal"]);
                    if (balanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal >= moneyamount)   //check if you can withdraw money
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE Account 
                                            SET WholeAccountBalance = WholeAccountBalance - @moneyamount, 
                                                BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal = BalanceAmountAvailableForWithdrawal - @moneyamount 
                                            WHERE accounNum = @accNum";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@moneyamount", moneyamount);

                        int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if (result == 1)
                            Console.WriteLine("Money withdrawn sucessfully.");
                        else
                            Console.WriteLine("Error while withdrawing, operation has failed.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Not enough money to withdrawn requested ammount.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Charging did not work");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Huge thanks, this worked! (just modified it a little, basically from english to my language)